# Are the words Element and Sequence reserved in Swift?

Tags: swift

In my (chemistry related) project, I'd like to use the words `Element`and `Sequence` for data structures. Will there be a conflict with the same names that are already used in Swift, should I rename them to `MyElement` and `MySequence` to be safe?

**UPDATE:**
I'm editing the question to hopefully make it more clear as was requested.  The following quote is from the Generics section of Apple's Swift documentation:

> Element defines a placeholder name for “some type Element” to be
>   provided later on. This future type can be referred to as “Element”
>   anywhere within the structure’s definition. In this case, Element is
>   used as a placeholder in three places

So, my question was if I can use the word `Element` for a structure without conflicting. The same for `Sequence` which I have seen used as well in sample code - although I cannot find it anymore.  The accepted answer below explains this.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: In my PlayGround setup sofar I haven't seen any errors or warnings. Just wanted to be sure that it is allowed, to anticipate any problems down the road.

Comment: My critique is that trying to anticipate all problems down the road is a waste of time and bandwidth. Be brave. _Go_ down the road and _see_ what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not reserved words in Swift. The identifier `Element` is used as an associated type inside some generic types in the standard library, but you can also use it for your own type if you want, although it might become confusing. The identifier `Sequence` is not currently used by the standard library.